# $\underline{\int_0^1} f(x) \, dx$ and $\overline{\int_0^1} f(x) \, dx$ if $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x) = -x$ when $x$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My book says $\underline{\int_0^1} f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2}$ and  $\overline{\int_0^1} f(x) \, dx = -\frac{1}{2}$.

I would think that the answers are $\underline{\int_0^1} f(x) \, dx = -\frac{1}{2}$ and  $\overline{\int_0^1} f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2}$. My understanding is that the lower integral is the supremum of all lower sums and that a lower sum is the sum of the product of the infimum of $f(x)$ on an interval and the length of the interval for all intervals on a partition of $[0, 1]$. Won't the infimum always be some value of $f(x)$ where $f(x)=-x$, since irrationals are dense in the reals, and thus there is always an irrational on any interval within a partition?

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong? By my reasoning, the lower integral should definitely be less than or equal to zero and the upper integral should be greater than or equal to zero. Apparently I've flipped it, though.

Comment: Typo in the book. By definition of the Darboux integral, the lower integral is *always* less than or equal to the upper integral.

Comment: Isn't the lower sum always going to be $\le$ the upper sum?

Comment: I mean lower integral and upper integral.

Comment: Yes-- of course, to the lower sum $\leq$ the upper sum. Should have been obvious to me that it was a typo. Thanks for the clarification.